# Why doesn't Django have a simpler way to style form fields?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I've looked at a lot of different methods on how to style form fields and all of them seem to be pretty unideal. Especially when you're trying to use bootstrap. I've done it a few different ways and I'm just surprised there isn't a better method than any of these.

Ex: Within the form file

```py
alias = forms.CharField(max_length=15, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username'}))
```

```py
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['alias'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'special'})
```

Ex: Doing it manually in the template as Django mentions (which I would rather not have to resort to doing)

Ex: with the django-widget-tweaks package (got errors saying incorrect inputs when they definitely were correct)

Is there another method or any instructions someone can point me to for what has worked well for them? Thanks.

Comment: Why not `CharField(max_length=15, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username', 'class': 'special'}))`?

Comment: You can use django crispy forms. Much easier way to implement forms and you can choose style formats like bootstrap and it will style your forms as such automatically.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I was reading about how its best to not mix business logic with presentation so I'm trying to avoid that solution as much as possible.

Comment: @devdob Crispy forms seems to be what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Try using crispy form tags which use the bootstrap 3 by default but you can change it in setting to bootstrap 4

https://www.merixstudio.com/blog/django-crispy-forms-what-are-they-about/